# Points on a circle hold weights. Finding the weight of an intermediate point?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm sorry if my terminology isn't just right - this isn't my field.

I have a handful of points on a circle, that indicate a weight.  I'd like to find that weight at any point on the circle that hasn't been defined explicitly.  The weights are continuous, so that between points 1 and 2, there are infinite points representing all values between the weight at point 1, and the weight at point 2.

What I'm trying now: for point 1 and point 2, or point 1 and point 'n' (the last point on the circle, before 1) - take the angle between point 1 and the next (previous) point.  Multiply the weight of point 1 by the sin of this angle, add it to the weight of the next (previous) point multiplied by the cosine of this angle, divide by two to get the average.

How far off am I?

(This is not for a class.  This is for a personal project.)

Comment: Just a question: suppose you have two point only, with given weights. How would you find the weight of a point in the middle between them?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this way you are doing a linear interpolation defined by cases (with angular points - roughly speaking) and could be good depending on your purposes. In my opinion a more smooth altough harder solution could be using the fourier approximation, try to read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation.